# Proving factorial attribute

Tags: factorial

Given that : $$ \sum_{i=1}^{k} a_i = n $$
I am asked to prove that:
$$\prod_{j=1}^{k} a_j! $$
divises $n!$

I saw that it works for $k=1$, and for $k=2$ I tried :

$$\frac{n!}{a_1!  a_2!} = \frac{(a_1 + a_2)!}{a_1! a_2!}$$

But came to nowhere.

How do I go on? I pretty sure it is by induction

Comment: It is by induction, but in this case, it requires you to show $k=2$ separately, and the rest follows by induction.

Comment: Indeed, and that's what I'm trying to do. If I can show it for k=2 then I can do it for k=j, let it be anything, for the induction. But I have to understand how to do k=2 first!

Comment: Did you recognize that you can write $\frac{(p+q)!}{p!q!}$ as a binomial coefficient?

Comment: To be honest, no I did not...

Comment: Thank you. A binomial coefficient is always a a positive integer in this case.

Comment: Yeah, it's provable for $k=2$ quickly of you know binomial coefficients. If you don't, the most direct approach is to show that, for any prime $p$, the maximal power of $p$ that divides the numerator is at least as big as the same value for the denominator. But binomials are far easier.

Comment: Why would I have to prove that a binomial coefficient is always a positive integer? From the hint in the answer below, it is the ways of choosing n balls from k sets where each set has $a_j$ balls. Clearly it is a positive integer...

Comment: As I said, if you don't know about binomials, proving that $(a+b)!$ is divisible by $a!b!$ requires that messy logic. If you know binomial theorem, that's different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

Count the number of ways of arranging $n$ balls where $a_1$ balls are of color $1$, $a_2$ balls of color $2$ and in general, $a_j$ balls are of color $j$. (Note that $\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^k a_j = n$.)

Comment: Now I get it.
It is the binomial coefficient, right?

Comment: @Aryabhata I have updated it. Does it read fine now?

Comment: @TheNotMe These are the [multinomial coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem).

Comment: This is more of a question that gives opinion about formality of mathematical proofs.
If I say that that number is what this is (arranging the balls), isn't it enough proof that it is an integer?

Answer (score 1):

Hint for induction proof.

If $$\sum_{i=1}^{k} a_j = n$$ then

$$\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} b_i = n$$

where $b_1 = a_1 + a_2, b_2 = a_3, \dots$

Since OP does not seem interested in this hint, for sake of completeness...

$$\dfrac{n!}{\prod_{j=1}^{k} a_j!}  = \dfrac{(a_1 + a_2)!}{a_1!a_2!}\cdot\dfrac{n!}{\prod_{j=1}^{k=1} b_j!}$$

which is the product of two integers.

Comment: +1. Another proof using induction is using the recurrence $$C(n+1;a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_k) = C(n;a_1-1,a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_k) + C(n;a_1,a_2-1,a_3,\ldots,a_k) + C(n;a_1,a_2,a_3-1,\ldots,a_k) + \cdots + C(n;a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_k-1)$$

Comment: @Marvis: I somehow find what I wrote easier :-), and is in fact another way of looking at your counting proof, I believe.